# Disabling services (daemons, agents) with launchctl

Tags: command-line, launchd, services, daemons

I want to get rid of some system services completely.
I turned off sip with `csrutil disable`.
Then following command

```
sudo launchctl disable com.apple.cloudphotod
```

Gave me an unexpected answer:

```
Unrecognized target specifier, did you mean
gui/501/com.apple.cloudphotod
```

I've read man, searched forums and so on. But I can't get why do I need specify the context agent is running in, how do I know that from `launchctl list` and is the a way to avoid the need to specify it?
There are many services and I'm completely uncertain which one is in which context.

Side question:
I also was looking for a gui tool such as Windows Services.msc, found Soma-zone's LaunchControl. Downloaded tar.gz archive, unarchived, started the app, and... it says "can't open the app".
Did I miss something and tar.gz needs some special handling? Never dealt with that.

Comment: RE: your "side question": It's been a while since I first installed `LaunchControl`, but IIRC: dbl-click on the `tar.xz` file decompresses it, leaving you with an`.app` file. Move that to your `Applications` folder. After that, if it won't start, you'll need to go into your `Systems Settings` app & figure out what to click to convince the "Apple Security Guardians" that you give permissions for it to run. There are probably better instructions at somazone.com - or email for tech support... Robby will answer & he's a great resource.

Comment: Sadly there hasn't been anything like this in settings app. But it lead me to think there are some rights problems with executable bin. And there was - tried `chmod`, got another error. Finally tried using archive tool instead of winzip - voila! It worked!

Comment: `winzip` - On a **Mac??**.  No wonder you had problems. :)  Anyway - glad to see you've resolved it. I think you'll like `LaunchControl`.

Answer (score 0):

Caveat: most of this is completely unoriginal on my part.

Here is a script which can stop and disable lots of macOS services. [Disable Sonoma Bloatware](https://gist.github.com/b0gdanw/812997a189f72f3953e0a1bb237f783d) by Bogdan. I know of this because Bogdan/b0gdanw is a regular and trusted MacRumors contributor. This list is for macOS Sonoma. Services  may be different for older macOS.

You will see that it correctly specifies the domain for each service. This is the `gui/501/` that you got as a suggestion. System daemons have `system` as domain.

So for your specific services the correct commands are:

```
launchctl bootout gui/501/com.apple.cloudphotod
launchctl disable gui/501/com.apple.cloudphotod
```

This assumes that your UID is 501 which is standard for the first admin user created at macOS installation.

Don't be tempted just to run the script! Heed the **WARNING! The script is meant to show how and what can be disabled. Don’t use it as it is, adapt it to your needs.**

As to why specify the domain: There may be more than one user on your Mac and each (if logged in at the same time) will have services running. And there are system services in their own domain `system`.

For a gui interface, I use two apps which do much the same thing:

- [LaunchControl](https://soma-zone.com/LaunchControl/) (which you have already discovered), and
- [Lingon](https://www.peterborgapps.com/lingon/).